# Convert nested error object with non-enumerable properties to enumberable?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which contains an error object. Th error object contains non-enumerable properties (`cause`, `message`, `stack`). The error can appear nested anywhere in the object. There may also be other objects with non enumerable properties but I wish these not to be changed to enumerable.

Example

```js
let one = { myErr: new Error() }
let two = { prop: { nested: new Error() } }
```

What is the most efficient of 'cloning' the object while achieving the following;

- The structure is preserved
- All non-enumerable properties are now enumerable
- The original stack trace is kept

I started a recursive function but stopped pretty quickly just trying to figure out how to replicate the structure;

```js
const parseObjects = (exception: any): any => {
  if (exception instanceof Error) {
    return parseErrors(exception)
  }

  if (typeof exception === 'object') {
    const properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(exception)

    for (const property of properties) {
      return parseObjects(exception[property])
    }
  }

  return exception;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to clone the objects (I assume from the fact that you put the word clone in quotes), then this works.

```js
function makeEnumerable(data: unknown) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).forEach(property => {
        Object.defineProperty(data, property, { enumerable: true });
    });
}

function makeEnumerableErrorsDeep(data: unknown) {
    if (data instanceof Error) {
        makeEnumerable(data);
    } else if (typeof data === 'object' && data != null) {
        for (const property in data) {
            makeEnumerableErrorsDeep(data[property as keyof typeof data])
        }
    }
}
```

[Working demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0CMMC8MDeMC2BPAogE6EBcMY8A7jEYSIQBQCUMAvgFCiSwLQBMaTDAAOdYWSwVo8ACZkK1WvWZs2ncNBgBDYltwAVRLHQBtBTWLKARPgBKtgPK2rTADTkqMfbmHwljJgBdAG52ABt4WGgtYABrfUIY+ENoUPYGADMAVzBgKABLcBgZeHhhADEcvMKwFQx2GEaYTKqCoqgQFKgAZSgY+MTgeDqGprHouISkrsEseGJ5T38GAHIAYSzoEGwcRAgtAHN4FZYOMdYmZlCLq-Z1SBAIgDowkAPVgFovj5gAIXgMvR4DBvh8TvcII94C83qskE84EYVu4AFLdBwAOSe0EI+TAB3yGVwDF4UCQ7hyJQyeNk7j4TCYEKhMPeKz4CNJyJgaMx2KguPxhOJpL4FLAVJpMjpDKZz1erIAgrpcIjoFyeVicXiCUSGDpEgYjGKJRQpTB6YyuJC5bCVr1+nBBsDOaj0Zr+dqhQwJgNpkaYJSAZLpYy7uxsrk2mAcFpYn4wFlsPMtAAjCIMGRaPpkHKxMAgShgFj1ACQDhTACt4HknkcoA5CwAFMTzKC4DFaJMQDNZrRMJ6Awj4GIACwYohAvkIbbQAD5MKMxo1y1Wayb4M3J63iZm+u4J1O2+45gmk4k0-AyPyssCLqFzkxrncI9UithY-HE8mL-4IAARUphB7bMAzAPMCyLBcxkJZpdy0GA8WiXJ4BADILDoQhi0XJd3zjfBT2-dM4MfbDWBgeAwggYEYJJHwULQuC0FQdAVhAStqygFYYAAMm44pexgABCdAEzCMIsKXJpB2aK1YAPbcEOjYioMknCP3wr9zwiX8ALKYCtBMeTpxVLQIBgONcFQuA6KsuDAkZVS1HOdgOHYXDPzPVNtMsQh-0AkkjCQRl3I0zyfx8vy9JFYL1IIrS-Ai3SgP1PQuhivC4q8hKMMioCfSmIY0ruK1mXlT5vhgBUMgQQgQW+cESptVl4VVTjXV5LVBV1UlyVA9czQtWVoTKtkOSRdr3QFHVhSMUU+qDU0QyGllViVA1WvVN0+Smr0UsNaBjQW2lzRlRrhtte04kdJINom7bPV1fKnS6Q7qUWk6mCAA)

Comment: I should have realised that 'mutation' was actually the safest and most simple course of action in this case. Thank you, works like a charm.